# Reading and tokenizing a file in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to figure out how to read some data about a travelling salesman problem from a file. I've included the first few lines of the file (the format is the same for the remaining 13503 lines so I've removed them). The file looks like this:

```
    NAME : usa12
    COMMENT : Cities with population at least 500 in 
    TYPE : TSP
    DIMENSION : 13509
    EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D
    NODE_COORD_SECTION
    1 245552.778 817827.778
    2 247133.333 810905.556
    3 247205.556 810188.889
    4 249238.889 806280.556
    5 250111.111 805152.778
    6 254475.000 804794.444
```

I'm interested in two things. The dimension value, and the city coordinates. Cities numbered `1,..,6` are shown (but there are 13509 of them), each of their `x` and `y` coordinates are adjacent. E.g. City 4 has `x=249238.889` and `y=806280.556`.
Basically I'd like to read my file and store the data like this:

```
int dimension = read dimension of 13509
Coordinate[] xy = create coordinates array, with coordinates of each city
```

Where a `coordinate` object is defined like this:

```
public class Coordinate {
    double x;
    double y;
    public Coordinate(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I guess I need to use a Buffered Reader, some IO exceptions and a String Tokenizer. I'm new to this, so I'm not really sure how to implement it. I don't know how to specifically read in the dimension value and the x and y coordinates. Does anyone have some suggested implementations?

Comment: so there is only one giant file which contains exactly 6 useless lines at the start and rest is the data which needs to be parsed?

Comment: @Doc There are multiple files of similar size, but I will only be reading one file each time the program is executed. So essentially, yes, each time the program is run, there is only one giant file. From this file, I only require the dimension integer value, and the coordinates of each city. All other data is useless. So there are exactly 5 useless lines.

Comment: 1. many files. 2. one at a time. 3. exactly 6 useless lines at start for each. 4. useful data till the end. 

Is it?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. There are 5 useless lines at the start of each file. The row called `DIMENSION` is useful. 4. Useful data until the last two rows (the last two lines are just blank lines).

Comment: ok. firing notepad :)

Comment: @Doc Nice one, thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to ignore the integers there? using StringTokenizer? 1,2,3 and etc.

Comment: posted the code. works fine for me. please clarify if I missed something.

Comment: @LiamWilson If it is a question, then yes you can ignore the integers. You don't need `StringTokenizer`. Simply splitting on the space character will give 3 splits in this case, first is the integer, next two will be the x and y values here. If you read my code then you will see there is `vals[1]` for x and `vals[2]` for y but not `vals[0]` because it is the integer we are ignoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a basic sample. Will update in case of changes.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class SO{
    public static void main(String...a)throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Start");


//Read thing
File f = new File("so_data.txt");

Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

int counts = 0;

s.nextLine();//skip 1
s.nextLine();//skip 2
s.nextLine();//skip 3
counts = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().split(" ")[2]);//use 4th
s.nextLine();//skip 5
s.nextLine();//skip 6
System.out.println(counts+" : counts");



counts = 6;//DUMMY DATA FOR TEST FILE - REMOVE FOR ACTUAL FILE

Coordinate[] xy = new Coordinate[counts];


int i = 0;

while(i<counts){ // picking exactly the required number of items.

            String line = s.nextLine();
            String[] vals = line.split(" ");

            double x = Double.parseDouble(vals[1]);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(vals[2]);

            Coordinate c =  new Coordinate(x,y);
//          System.out.println(c);
            xy[i++] = c;
        }


for( i = 0;i<xy.length;i++)
            System.out.println("for index "+i+") "+xy[i]);

    }
}
 class Coordinate {
    double x;
    double y;
    public Coordinate(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Coord:: "+x+" , "+y;
    }
}
```

---

`so_data.txt`

```
NAME : usa12
COMMENT : Cities with population at least 500 in 
TYPE : TSP
DIMENSION : 13509
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
1 245552.778 817827.778
2 247133.333 810905.556
3 247205.556 810188.889
4 249238.889 806280.556
5 250111.111 805152.778
6 254475.000 804794.444
```

Comment: This looks like it may work! I will test this out!
I'm not sure, but I think there needs to be a `try` and `catch` somewhere. Where does this go exactly?